# JavaFX - Different default CSS windows and linux?

Tags: css, javafx-8

JavaFX 8 on windows (1.8.0_231) uses Modena css, on Linux (1.8.0_92) it is using CASPIAN css

The documentation states JavaFX 8 uses Modena as default?

Why is CASPIAN being used as the default?

Comment: Can you give a link to the documentation that states that, I can't find it immediately. Thanks.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/jfx-overview.htm

Modena theme. The Modena theme replaces the Caspian theme as the default for JavaFX 8 applications. The Caspian theme is still available for your use by adding the setUserAgentStylesheet(STYLESHEET_CASPIAN) line in your Application start() method. For more information, see the Modena blog at fxexperience.com